# Matplotlib FuncAnimation freezes when block argument is set to False

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code, matplotlib opens a window but then freezes, even though the code is still executing. If the `block=False` argument is removed from `pyplot.show()`, `FuncAnimation` generates the graph as expected but blocks the code so the loop is never reached.

```
from random import uniform
from time import sleep

from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation  


class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = []
        self.y = []

        tup = pyplot.subplots(1, 2)
        self.figure = tup[0]
        self.figure.set_figwidth(10)
        self.figure.set_figheight(5)
        self.axis1 = tup[1][0]
        self.line1 = self.axis1.plot([], [], color='r')[0]
        self.ani = FuncAnimation(self.figure, func=self.gen_data, repeat=False, interval= 100)

    def gen_data(self, i):
        self.x.append(i)
        self.y.append(uniform(i / 2, i))
        self.axis1.set_xlim(0, max(self.x))
        self.axis1.set_ylim(0, max(self.y))
        self.line1.set_data(self.x, self.y)


test = A()
pyplot.show(block= False)

for i in range(0, 5):
    print('can I get here?') # yes, but where is my graph?
    sleep(2)
```

I want to use it to monitor object state as it does some computational work so I really need the non-blocking functionality, is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

With `pyplot.show(block=False)`, the interactive backend is not allowed to process any events before the function returns, therefore nothing is displayed.

Try replacing `pyplot.show(block=False)` with `pyplot.pause(.01)`, and `sleep(2)` with `pyplot.pause(2)` and see if the behavior is to your liking. [`pyplot.pause()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pause.html#matplotlib-pyplot-pause) is a close relative of `pyplot.show()`. It allows you to have the behavior of `pyplot.show(block=True)` but for a defined period of time.

On the other hand you might want to run the display for a minimal blocking of time and get back to calculating. In that case, [`pyplot.gcf().canvas.flush_events()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_bases_api.html?highlight=flush_events#matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureCanvasBase.flush_events) may be a more appropriate replacement for `sleep(2)`.

The documentation on the [interactive](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/interactive.html?highlight=flush_events#interactive-mode) features of matplotlib figures may help give more context for understanding the difference between these options.

### Code with updates

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from random import uniform
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Qt5Agg')  # causes plotting into external figure


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = []
        self.y = []

        tup = plt.subplots(1, 2)
        self.figure = tup[0]
        self.figure.set_figwidth(10)
        self.figure.set_figheight(5)
        self.axis1 = tup[1][0]
        self.line1 = self.axis1.plot([], [], color='r')[0]
        self.ani = FuncAnimation(self.figure, func=self.gen_data, repeat=False, interval=100)

    def gen_data(self, i):
        self.x.append(i)
        self.y.append(uniform(i / 2, i))
        self.axis1.set_xlim(0, max(self.x))
        self.axis1.set_ylim(0, max(self.y))
        self.line1.set_data(self.x, self.y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = A()
    plt.pause(.01)

    for i in range(0, 5):
        print('can I get here?')  # yes, but where is my graph?
        plt.pause(2)
```

### Console Output

- Run in PyCharm 2021.1.2 (Professional Edition) Build #PY-211.7442.45, built on June 1, 2021
- `matplotlib v3.4.2`

```py
Python 3.8.10 (default, May 19 2021, 13:12:57) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
runfile('E:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/test/test10.py', wdir='E:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/test')
E:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/test/test10.py:24: UserWarning: Attempting to set identical left == right == 0 results in singular transformations; automatically expanding. self.axis1.set_xlim(0, max(self.x))
E:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/test/test10.py:25: UserWarning: Attempting to set identical bottom == top == 0 results in singular transformations; automatically expanding. self.axis1.set_ylim(0, max(self.y))
can I get here?
can I get here?
can I get here?
can I get here?
can I get here?
```

### Plot Output

[image]